# Can you insert or update a row based on multiple values being identical in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm not very experienced with SQLite, and I want to perform some operations based on a local database. My data consists of a lot of entries of one ID, and there are some additional IDs to specify the data. Based on multiple IDs, there should be a unique combination for each entry in the table.

I would like to select (if it exists) a row based on a combination of IDs, and either insert or update some columns in that row.

I haven't really tried anything because I can't find where to start.

But to illustrate what I mean, I would think of something like this:
UPDATE OR REPLACE INTO my_table (ID,Part_ID,Location_ID,Torque) VALUES (2,6,4,100) WHERE (ID,Part_ID,Location_ID) = (2,6,4)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a *unique constraint* for the combination of the columns `ID`, `Part_ID` and `Location_ID`, which you can define with a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_my_table ON my_table (ID, Part_ID, Location_ID);
```

Then use [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

```
INSERT INTO my_table (ID, Part_ID, Location_ID, Torque) VALUES (2, 6, 4, 100)
ON CONFLICT(ID, Part_ID, Location_ID) DO UPDATE
SET Torque = EXCLUDED.Torque;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FAQ-72TW).